# git doesn't ignore file while it matches with a wildcard in gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a gitignore line like this

```
*.user # Qt Creator backup files
```

... and it doesn't match CMakeLists.txt.user! How come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the line *# Qt Creator backup files* isn't a comment, only lines starting with a # are a comment, as in the manual

> A line starting with # serves as a comment.

So the line `*.user # Foo`  tries to match a file with exactly `*.user # Foo`, not `*.user`